# Bulk replace values in XML file through Notepad++

Tags: xml, notepad++, bulkupdate

I am trying to do a bulk update where I copy the values of one tag to another but have not had any luck. Would appreciate any help that could be provided!

Here is an example of what want to do.

```
Old
<name>ABC</name>
<description>old text</description>

New
<name>ABC</name>
<description>ABC</description>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Notepad++ has **XML Tools** plugin. That plugin supports **XSLT**. XSLT will help you to achieve what you need.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the following: (1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic of what needs to be done.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.

Comment: All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: I tried to include as text but it would remove the content within chevrons. is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: You need to select it (highlight it) and click **Ctrl+K**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution based on XSLT.

It is using a so called *Identity Transform* pattern.

Notable points:

- The XSLT will copy the entire input XML as-is except the
  `<description>` elements.
- Each `<description>` elements will get value of the sibling `<name>`
  element.

In the Notepad++ select the following option in the menu:

```
Plugins => XML Tools => XSL Transformation...
```

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <item id="1">
        <name>ABC</name>
        <description>old text</description>
    </item>
    <item id="2">
        <name>BBC</name>
        <description>some text</description>
    </item>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
                encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity transform-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="description">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::name"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<root>
  <item id="1">
    <name>ABC</name>
    <description>ABC</description>
  </item>
  <item id="2">
    <name>BBC</name>
    <description>BBC</description>
  </item>
</root>
```

Comment: apologies, but how do i implement this? i am new to working with these tools. I installed the xml plugin though

Comment: I added it to the answer.

Comment: so it seemed to make the edit, but it created a new text doc in doing so instead of updating the xml file itself

Comment: That's correct and expected behavior. It allows the following: (1) preserve the original document, and (2) compare with the newly created XML file. If you don't need it, you can delete the original XML file.